# AngularJS service to initialize and get a third party component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a map-centric application with angularjs and esri arcgis.

I would like to create a seperate service which provides a `getMap` method that would return the map (after initialized) and an `initMap` method which does the initialization:

```
// in my controller:
MapService.initMap();
$scope.map = MapService.getMap();
```

MapService.js:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('MapService',  function($q, esriLoader) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        this.getMap = function(){
            if ( angular.isDefined( deferred ) ) return $q.when( deferred );
        }

        var self = this;
        this.initMap = function() {

            esriLoader.require(['esri/Map'],
                function(Map) { 

                    console.log('require callback');

                    // Create the map
                    self.map = new Map({
                        basemap: 'satellite'
                    });


                    console.log('resolve map');

                    deferred.resolve(map);


                });

        }

    });
```

I get an error on the `deferred.resolve(map)` line because deferred is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide demo on plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: You have a scope variable issue. Change  var deferred to this.deferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.getMap = function(){
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then use:

```
MapService.getMap().then(function (map) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did fix the error message I had before! But strangely, there seems to be a problem when I resolve my promise within the esriLoader.require function (this is another deferred callback which loads some required JS files first in order to create the map). When I resolve my deferred variable with some random data as the first thing in the initMap method, without the whole esriLoader.require call, it does reach the 'then' code in my controller -  with the code above, it doesn't, even though the 'resolve' is happening...I checked that. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @user66875 I think callback is not called -> `function(Map) {`

Comment: hmm the callback is actually called. I added two console.log lines in my code, both are actually displayed in the console.